# IONIC2 Increment badges while app in background on android when push notification is received via fireBase

Tags: android, firebase, cordova-plugins, ionic3, badge

I have a Ionic3 app using firebase and cordova-plugin-badge.
If the app is running in the foreground and I receive a push notification the badge number is increased.

```
import { Badge } from '@ionic-native/badge';
declare let FCMPlugin;

constructor(private badge: Badge) {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    FCMPlugin.onNotification((data) => {
      this.badge.increase(1); // works when app is in foreground
      if (data.wasTapped) {
        //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
        this.handleNotificationsWhenInBackground(data);
      } else {
        //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
        this.handleNotificationsWhenInForeground(data);
      }
    },
    (msg) => {
    },
    function (err) {
    });
  });
}
```

I receive the push notification when the app is in the background but badge number is not incremented. If I click on the push notification received on android while the app is in the background then badge number is incremented. So the code to increment the badge number is called only when the app is in foreground.

My problem is: how to increment the badge number while the app is in the background and I receive a push notification.

Comment: have you solved the problem? Any solution available?

Comment: no, for users who use android version 8+ this is done out of the box (by the os) and it is not necessary anymore

Comment: It doesnt seem to be working right for me. When i use this.badge.get the value being returned doesnt match the actual badge value ( if the badge value was generated by a notification sent in the background ). It doesnt seem to take those notification into account.

Comment: I am however only sending data payload and no notification payload

Comment: sorry haven't gone that deep in the use you are describing and now don't have access to the application code since I don't work at that employee anymore

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to set a property in your notification payload, like if you are on Android, you have to set `"click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"` property to enable doing some action after user tapping on the notification tray.